# Get Bitmap from Mobile vision's face tracking camera

Tags: android, mobile, bitmap, vision

I am trying to get a bitmap from mobile vision's face tracking camera but after about 5 hours of trying, i am kind of stuck.

I. Firstly, Result: Blank image with

```
Bitmap image = mSurfaceView.getDrawingCache().
```

I already set true for SetDrawingCache in here:

```
    public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    mStartRequested = false;
    mSurfaceAvailable = false;
    mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());

    //HERE
    mSurfaceView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    addView(mSurfaceView);
    }
```

II. After that i tried: Take screenshot of Graphic OVerlay, and get a shot from camera, then merge these 2 bitmap -> Result: Horrible. Everything need to be right is wrong.

If anyone can come up with any solutions( even suggestions are fine), i would be very appreciated.

Quan.

Comment: Can you add the bitmaps? "Result: Horrible. Everything need to be right is wrong." is not very informative. Also, how do you merge BMPs?

Comment: Yes, i can add them together. But the bitmap from screenshooting graphicoverlay is bigger than the one i get from my facetracking camera. So the result is very weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 8 hours of trying. I get this workaround.

First, i get the overlay screenshot with it's X and Y in the facetracking camera:

```
overlay = screenShot(mGraphicOverlay);
final float overlayX = mGraphicOverlay.getX();
final float overlayY =  mGraphicOverlay.getY();
```

Then i take a picture from the camera. Resize the overlay to fit the picture from the camera. After that i merge those 2 into 1 bitmap. And send it back to main activity.

```
 mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {
                    //Bitmap loadedImage = null;
                    loaded = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
                    Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                    rotateMatrix.postRotate(90);
                    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loaded, 0, 0,
                            loaded.getWidth(), loaded.getHeight(),
                            rotateMatrix, false);

                    overlay = resize(overlay,rotatedBitmap.getWidth(), rotatedBitmap.getHeight());


                    merged = MergeBitmap(rotatedBitmap, overlay, overlayX, overlayY);

                    Intent myIntentA1A2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    merged.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    //imgDecodableString = BitMapToString(GlobalResource.glass);
                    myIntentA1A2.putExtra("Image", encoded);

                    context.startActivity(myIntentA1A2);
```

Comment: can you post full solution, i am also stuck here since 2 days and still not able to merge with loaded bitmap and overlay. Thanks

Comment: i am trying like this
Bitmap  overlay = takeScreenshotForView(mGraphicOverlay);

                                Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                                rotateMatrix.postRotate(90);
                                rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0,
                                        loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(),
                                        rotateMatrix, false);
                                overlay = MergeBitmap(rotatedBitmap, overlay);
                                saveToInternalStorage(overlay);

Comment: It's not a complete answer. It would be nice if you edit the post and give the full solution.